# Embed YouTube video in iOS without auto fullscreen

Tags: html, ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to embed a YouTube video on my app in Xcode. When I click on video on the simulator it automatically goes to full screen as the picture below shown. Is it possible to stop my video going to full screen automatically?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        var html = "<html><body><iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/W7qWa52k-nE\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"

        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: delete `allowfullscreen` in the iframe?

Answer (score 11):

You need to allow in-line playback:

```
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

// add ?playsinline=1 to your YouTube video URL
let embededHTML = "<html><body><iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/W7qWa52k-nE?playsinline=1\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"

webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
```

Comment: can we auto play the video?

Comment: @QadirHussain Sure, add autoplay=1 after playsinline=1

Comment: I have done like this and I am testing it in iOS 9.O ipad and is not working.

Comment: @QadirHussain Ask a new question and post the full code you are using.  The post the link back here and I'll take a look.

Comment: I have added 
 webview.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
 webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

but still no luck :(

Comment: `enablejsapi=1` should also be added as a parameter. Btw, since you're using embedded video: if you want to prevent the error _"This video contains content from _ _ _. It is restricted from playback on certain sites."_ you can use `URL(string: "http://www.youtube.com")` as baseURL. It must be http, not https. Then you won't have the problem of missing the 'referrer' HTTP header field, which is why some embeds are rejected with this error.